# Error getting thrown outside of promise.catch

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-promise

I'm confused as to why this error (shown in code) triggers both the Promise catch and the try-catch:

```
async dispatch => {
    try {
      let dataUrl = await getBlob(url).catch(ex => {
        console.log(ex);   <=== This triggers
        return url;
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);  <=== This triggers
    }
}
```

and getBlob looks like this:

```
getBlob = url =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
      } else {
        throw new Error("...");  <=== Error thrown
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `getBlob()` function throws an error that triggers the `catch` for getBlob().

Now when that catch is triggered, the `try/catch` block considers as if it is being failed and ultimately triggers the outer catch.

You can have something like this:

```
async dispatch => {
    try {
      let dataUrl = await getBlob(url);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);  <=== This triggers
    }
}
```

The outer `catch` will catch any error for `getBlob()` no need to add a `catch`

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if I do want to catch it in the `.catch` and prevent the `try-catch` from triggering?

Comment: @K41F4r Don't let the promise fail. Do everything in `.then()` but that won't be a good approach at all.